# How to install or manage RabbitMQ plugins in PCF Dev

Tags: rabbitmq, cloud-foundry, pcf, pcfdev

I have newly installed and started pcf dev instance (with one of the latest versions on the current date -  0.30.0).

I have added rabbitmq as a Service for one of my spaces (using command `cf create-service p-rabbitmq standard my_rabbitmq`).

There is no rabbitmq management dashboard in the web application interface, probably because i am using pcf **dev**, not the cloud pcf instance.

Is it possible to manage(and how) rabbitmq plugins using command line tools or somehow else?

p.s. I have Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `cf dev ssh` to get SSH access to the VM as the vcap user.
2. Thanks to https://github.com/pivotal-cf/pcfdev/issues/67

> You can log in as root and run the following:
>
> root@agent-id-pcfdev-0:~# export PATH=/var/vcap/packages/erlang/bin:/var/vcap/packages/rabbitmq-server/bin:$PATH
>
> root@agent-id-pcfdev-0:~# rabbitmq-plugins enable

3. To login as a root https://askubuntu.com/questions/91598/how-do-i-login-as-root:

> Be aware that the root account is not active by default.
>
> You will need to do:
>
> sudo passwd root
>
> Then go ahead to set password. Use the root user using
>
> su root